# How to convert decimal to hex using c#?

Tags: c#, ascii

I have a program written in Delphi is converting 11 to **0xB** and 28 to **0x1c**. I tried to convert 11 (decimal to Hex) in c# using this:-

```
var deciValue01 = 11;
var deciValue02 = 28;
var deciValue03 = 13;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("11 = {0:x}", deciValue01));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("28 = {0:x}", deciValue02));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("13 = {0:x}", deciValue03));
```

but the results I am getting is:-

- 11 = b
- 28 = 1c
- 13 = d

Wondering how to convert 11 to '0xB' and 28 to '0x1c' and 13 to '0xD'? Isn't it I need to change from Decimal to Hex?

Comment: So you want to add a "0x" prefix? Why not simply add it as a literal? `Format("0x{0:X}")`

Comment: And use `"0x{0:X}" to make the hex characters uppercase instead of lowercase, because it sems you want that.

Comment: What you are getting is exactly right?  Just add `Ox` to the string you generate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `X` to make it capital hex digits instead of lower case, and add the `0x` yourself:

```
// Add using System.Diagnostics; at the top of the file... no need to
// explicitly qualify all your type names
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("11 = 0x{0:X}", deciValue01));
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("28 = 0x{0:X}", deciValue02));
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("13 = 0x{0:X}", deciValue03));
```

Note that the `deciValue01` values are neither "decimal" nor "hex" themselves. They're just numbers. The concept of "decimal" or "hex" only makes sense when you're talking about a textual representation, at least for integers. (It matters for floating point, where the set of representable types depends on the base used.)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(/*"HexValue"*/);
String hexRepresentation = Convert.ToString(value, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want this...

```
var deciValue01 = 11;
var deciValue02 = 28;
var deciValue03 = 13;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("11 = 0x{0:x}", deciValue01));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("28 = 0x{0:x}", deciValue02));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("13 = 0x{0:x}", deciValue03));
```